# How can we add a virtual drive to a multipass VM instance?

Tags: multipass

I am trying to add a virtual drive to a VM instance created by multipass. I am not able to find the command line options in multipass for doing the task.

Comment: No, this is not supported: https://github.com/canonical/multipass/issues/2303